# Passing scope to forEach

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a callback method `addToCount` instead of anonymous function in `forEach`. But I can't access `this.count` in it (returns `undefined`).

```
function Words(sentence) {
  this.sentence = sentence;
  this.count = {};
  this.countWords();
}

Words.prototype = {
  countWords: function() {
    var words = this.sentence.split(/\W+/);
    words.forEach(this.addToCount);
  },
  addToCount: function(word) {
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    if (word == '') return;
    if (word in this.count)
      this.count[word] += 1;
    else
      this.count[word] = 1;
  }
}
```

I think the problem is the scope. How can I pass `this` to `addToCount` or is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: words.forEach(this.addToCount, this);

Comment: Perfect & succinct

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You need to use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind a scope:

```
words.forEach(this.addToCount.bind(this));
```

Note that this is not available in all browsers: you should use a shim (as provided in the link above) to add it in the browsers that don't support `Function#bind`.

---

As dandavis points out in the comments, you can pass a value to [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as the context for the callback:

```
words.forEach(this.addToCount, this);
```

Comment: @lonesomeday - I would recommend swapping the two answers above because the second one is probably the better way of doing this today, if you are not using ES6.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. I've used `that` rather than `_this` but also I've moved `addToCount` so it's inside `countWords`. That turns `countWords` into a closure containing that.

```
Words.prototype = {
  countWords: function() {
    var that = this, words = this.sentence.split(/\W+/);
    words.forEach(function(word) {
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        if (word == '') return;
        if (word in that.count)
          that.count[word] += 1;
        else
          that.count[word] = 1;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I had in the beginning and I'm trying to refactor that.