# Angular2 forEach cant read property

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

How can I call `this.firms` within a data `forEach()`?

I know how to do this in Angular1, but not with my current project in Angular 2.

Currently it works fine outside of the forEach, but not within.

```
 console.log(this.firms[0].name); // works
    var a = 0;
        console.log("--------------");

    data.forEach(function (eachObj) {
      console.log("firms check!");
      console.log(this.firms); // not working
      a = a + eachObj.income; 
      eachObj.name = this.firms[data.firmid - 1].name; // wont work
    });
```

Error:

```
Cannot read property 'firms' of undefined
```

Comment: Please provide us with a https://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing scope to forEach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733758/passing-scope-to-foreach)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The context `this` is not injected in the anonymous function called by the `forEach()`. That's why `this` is undefined.

You can either use the `arrow function` if you're using ES6 features, as it keeps the context in the function:

```
data.forEach(eachObj => {
  console.log("firms check!");
  console.log(this.firms);
  a = a + eachObj.income; 
  eachObj.name = this.firms[data.firmid - 1].name;
});
```

Or simply bind the context directly:

```
data.forEach(function (eachObj) {
  console.log("firms check!");
  console.log(this.firms);
  a = a + eachObj.income; 
  eachObj.name = this.firms[data.firmid - 1].name;
}.bind(this));
```

**Edit**:

As mentioned by [zeroflagL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151351/zeroflagl), you could simply pass the context to the `forEach()`:

```
data.forEach(function (eachObj) {
  console.log("firms check!");
  console.log(this.firms);
  a = a + eachObj.income; 
  eachObj.name = this.firms[data.firmid - 1].name;
}, this);
```

Comment: I have the same problem and I am using angular 7 and none of the solution worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to make the `data` to be and array

like so :

```
Array.from(data).forEach((eachObj) => {
    console.log("firms check!"); 
    console.log(that.firms);
    eachObj.name = that.firms[data.firmid - 1].name;
})
```

This will work as well

Answer (score 1):

That's the basic example for scope in javascript.
Inside your function `this` refers to the context of the function itself. The outside world isn't accessable.

Since you're using Typescript with angular you can just use an `arrow function`:

```
data.forEach((eachObj) => {
  console.log("firms check!");
  console.log(this.firms); // not working
  a = a + eachObj.income; 
  eachObj.name = this.firms[data.firmid - 1].name; // wont work
});
```

This will preserve the scope and your `this` is available inside it. 
In plain javascript you could do something like this:

```
var that = this;

data.forEach(function (eachObj) {
  console.log("firms check!");
  console.log(that.firms); // not working
  a = a + eachObj.income; 
  eachObj.name = that.firms[data.firmid - 1].name; // wont work
});
```