# Cannot read property of undefined and this pointing not in the right place

Tags: javascript

I have **Cannot read property 'convertIntoCorrectDate' of undefined** error.

I think when I call this.convertIntoCorrectDate, this refers to *objectResa* and not my component.
I tried to call myComp.convertIntoCorrectDate instead but it triggers error too (*myComp.convertIntoCorrectDate is not a function*).

Do you know how I can call my function ?

````
class myComp extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      //        this.convertIntoCorrectDate = this.convertIntoCorrectDate.bind(this);
    }

    fillBooking(responseJson){
        var reservations = responseJson.reservations;
        reservations.forEach(function(objectResa) {
              var aResaEvent = {
                     id: objectResa.resa.ID,
                     start: this.convertIntoCorrectDate(objectResa.resa.start), 
                     end: this.convertIntoCorrectDate(objectResa.resa.end)
              };
              console.log(aResaEvent);
        });

    }

    convertIntoCorrectDate(date){
        // code to be written
        return "0";
    }
```
````

Comment: Where is `convertServerDateToOutlookDate`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing scope to forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733758/passing-scope-to-foreach)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava sorry it isconvertIntoCorrectDate, I renamed the function in my question to simplify. I edited my question to correct

Comment: You should take a look at arrow functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your `fillBooking(responseJson)` function to:

```
fillBooking = (responseJson) => {
```

and the `forEach` to:

```
reservations.forEach((objectResa) => {
```

(to arrow functions), the `this` should point to the scope you desire.