# Why can I not use getElementById as a callback to Array#map?

Tags: javascript, dom, array-map

To map an array of stringified numbers to actual Numbers, I can simply pass the Number function:

```js
let arr = ["0", "1", "-2.5"];

console.log(arr.map(Number));
```

Now I would like to use the same approach with `document.getElementById` to map a list of `id` strings to their corresponding DOM nodes:

```js
let arr = ["a", "b"];

console.log(arr.map(document.getElementById));
```

```html
<div id="a">a <span id="b">b</span></div>
```

which gives me

```bash
"TypeError: 'getElementById' called on an object that does not implement interface Document."
```

Can someone explain the error?

Comment: It's the same issue as in [Passing scope to forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733758/passing-scope-to-foreach).

Comment: BTW, the first parameter of `.map` is not a predicate (as if its truthfulness would matter), but a mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an explanation of what is happening [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Called_on_incompatible_type):

> When this error is thrown, a function (on a given object), is called with a `this` not corresponding to the type expected by the function.
>
> This issue can arise when using the `Function.prototype.call()` or `Function.prototype.apply()` methods, and providing a `this` argument which does not have the expected type.
>
> This issue **can also happen when providing a function that is stored as a property of an object as an argument to another function**. In this case, the object that stores the function won't be the `this` target of that function when it is called by the other function. To work-around this issue, you will either need to provide a lambda which is making the call, or use the `Function.prototype.bind()` function to force the `this` argument to the expected object.

I also add my alternative solution: there is [an overload of the method `map` that allows you to set the context in the second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#thisarg):

```js
let arr = ["a", "b"];

console.log(arr.map(document.getElementById, document));
```

```html
<div id="a">a <span id="b">b</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting, it seems to be related to `this` no longer pointing to the correct context (which would be `document`) when passing `document.getElementById` as a callback to `map`, so explicitly passing a bound `getElementById` does the trick:

```js
let arr = ["a", "b"];

console.log(arr.map(document.getElementById.bind(document)));
```

```html
<div id="a">a <span id="b">b</span></div>
```

Unfortunately, this also kind of defeats the purpose of the approach, which would be conciseness, as this can be shortened from

```js
arr.map(document.getElementById.bind(document))
// to
arr.map(id=>document.getElementById(id))
```

Comment: `arr.map(x => document.getElementById(x)` also works.

Comment: @Andy Sure, as would `arr.map(n=>Number(n))`. But in case of Number it's just so much more concise.

Comment: *"`this` losing the correct context"*: that is a strange way of putting it. There is nothing that loses anything here. `this` is determined at the moment of the call, and if the caller does not do `document.getElementById(...)`, but does `callback(...)`, then there is no `this` argument passed with that call.

Comment: @Trincot I'd be thankful if you added a more precise answer. I'd delete my own then.